# Fatal error on buddypress/ buddypress portfolio and bounce theme

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Please I need someone to help me out. I installed wordpress and buddypress. I'm using a theme called Bounce. I need my members to be able to upload projects in form of a portfolio so I installed a plugin called buddypress portfolio. Every thing works fine until I hit the "add" button which is supposed to allow users add items to their portfolios and I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function messages_remove_callback_values() in /home/nigeri44/public_html/wp-content/plugins/buddypress-portfolio/includes/bp-portfolio-screens.php on line 43

The theme developer can't help cos he says it's a plugin issue and the plugin developers will say the reverse it the case. I need someone to please point me in the right direction.

The website is: www.nigeriaprints.com

Thank you for your time

Comment: That is obviously in the plugin -- just look at the file name where the error occurred.  Have you tried contacting the plugin developers?

Comment: I haven't. The developer's site doesn't seem to function anymore. his website is supposed to be shatter.fr

Comment: It sounds like you need a different plugin -- this one is busted and the developer is no longer around.

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that. This seems to be the only plugin that does anything close to what I need.